# Should I await async calls like MessageDialog and Launcher methods?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-8, windows-runtime, async-await

Visual studio is giving me all sorts of warnings about not awaiting my `MessageDialog.ShowAsync()` and `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync()` methods.

It says:

> "consider applying the await keyword"

Obviously I don't NEED to await them but is would it be beneficial to?

Awaiting the call obviously blocks the UI thread which is bad - so why does Visual Studio throw up so many warnings?

Comment: Does http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh965065.aspx help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Awaiting the call obviously blocks the UI thread which is bad

`await` doesn't actually block the UI. `await` suspends the execution of the method until the awaited task completes and then continues the rest of the method. Read more about [await (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx).

> Obviously I don't NEED to await them but is would it be beneficial to?

If you don't use `await`, then the method calling `MessageDialog.ShowAsync()` may be completed before `MessageDialog.ShowAsync()` is completed. You don't need to, but it's good practice.

For example, let's say you want to download a string and use it, without await:

```
async void MyAsyncMethod()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var task = client.GetStringAsync("http://someurl.com/someAction");

    // Here, GetStringAsync() may not be finished when getting the result
    // and it will block the UI thread until GetStringAsync() is completed.
    string result = task.Result;
    textBox1.Text = result; 
}
```

But if we use `await`:

```
async void MyAsyncMethod()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    string result = await client.GetStringAsync("http://someurl.com/someAction");

    // This method will be suspended at the await operator, 
    // awaiting GetStringAsync() to be completed,
    // without freezing the UI, and then continues this method.

    textBox1.Text = result;
}
```

Comment: The first version of the method blocks the calling/UI thread until the task completes when you access the Result property.

Comment: @JamesManning You are correct, what was I thinking. I updated the comments. Next time I'll do a better example =) Thanks for pointing it out.